# wordpress woocommerece add to cart button

Tags: php, css

I have a serious coding error on a woo-commerce shop page in a wordpress site, the add to cart but is not displaying add to cart but displaying code which my clients customer wont understand. See code below

```
data-product_id="705" data-product_sku="1" aria-label="Add “Echoes of Reflections” to your cart" rel="nofollow"
```

Add to cart error image displaying in shop:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Note that this is not a forum like you may know it. Use our guide [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what makes a good question for this place. In particular, it is *very* helpful if you add a [mcve] to your question. You can [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Please check some PHP echo OR print not hided.

Answer (score 0):

Might be issue with your theme. Change your theme and see.